# Query with FORMAT() function fails after upgrading to VS 17.8

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I have this method in Visual Basic that populates a DataAdapter from MS Access for a report in VisualBasic. The query statement uses the `FORMAT` to format a date to avoid displaying hour, minutes and seconds, and has worked well for a long time.

Now I updated Visual Studio to version 17.8.0 and this query doesn't work anymore! What is wrong in this statement? It still works when run directly in Access.

```
rsQry = "SELECT FORMAT(RegProduzione.[DATA], 'dd-mm-yyyy') AS DATAG,RegProduzione.TURNO, 
RegProduzione.DISEGNO, RegProduzione.MATRICOLA,RegProduzione.Acqua_OK, 
RegProduzione.ACQUA_NOK, RegProduzione.[Note] 
FROM (RegProduzione) 
WHERE RegProduzione.Data = #" & Form_Sinottico.T_DataC.Text & "# AND 
RegProduzione.Turno = " & Form_Sinottico.T_TurnoC.Text & " ORDER BY 
RegProduzione.Data DESC"
```

Comment: 1.) Use parameterized queries. Your query is ripe for an SQL Injection attack. 2.) Don't format the date in your query. Format it in the presentation layer when putting it on-screen or on a report.

Comment: SQL SERVER in SSms doesn#t like your parenthesis around RegProduzione

Comment: Access is nothing like SQL Server and has a very different syntax. Dates aren't surrounded by `#` in SQL Server. Even if that was fixed, the query would still be wide open to SQL injection and conversion error problems. Imagine what would happen if `T_TurnoC.Text` contained `O'Reilly` or `' OR 1=1; DROP TABLE Users; --`. The only reason you don't encounter that with Access so frequently is that Access is only used in small or single-user applications.

Comment: `i changed my VisualStudio to version 17.8.0 and this query doesn't work anymore!` it never did. The code editor's version doesn't affect the query syntax of whatever database the compiled executable connects to

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, you are right!

Comment: Please post errors or undesired results. *It doesn't work* is never a helpful descriptor. In Access, if you want to parameterize dates, consider passing string parameter into `CDate`.

Answer (score 0):

I formatted the Date field directly on the report.
This is the code I used with Microsoft ReportViewer:

```
=FormatDateTime(Fields!DATAG.Value,DateFormat.ShortDate)
```

Comment: I hope you fixed that massive injection issue at the same time

Comment: @ThomA, yes! I did! :-)